# Python - import a python program using a local variable in main

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program say program1.py in this format

```
import configparser
def main():
    args = config.get_value('DEFAULT')
    var1 = args.get('variable1')
    function1(var1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('settings.ini')
    main()
```

How do I import program1 and execute the main function when config is just passed when the program is used as a script?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it into this:

```
import configparser
def main():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('settings.ini')
    args = config.get_value('DEFAULT')
    var1 = args.get('variable1')
    function1(var1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I know a few workarounds but I wanted to know how to get it to work as is.